# Failed to load http://localhost:5000/.well-known/openid-configuration: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, identityserver4

I am a newbie to identityserver4, recently I have seen the Quickstart8 sample provided by the identityserver team, in that 3 project are included 1.Identityserver 
2. Api 3.Client all are working fine in the browser when I deployed to iis they are not working properly it is showing error like...

[image]

I am using javascript client ...

Please help me with this issue.

This is my code...

Api (startup.cs)

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;

namespace Api
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddMvcCore()
                .AddAuthorization()
                .AddJsonFormatters();
        services.AddAuthentication("Bearer")
            .AddIdentityServerAuthentication(options =>
            {
                options.Authority = "http://localhost:5000";
                options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;

                options.ApiName = "api1";
            });

        services.AddCors(options =>
        {
            // this defines a CORS policy called "default"
            options.AddPolicy("default", policy =>
            {
                policy.WithOrigins("http://localhost:5003")
                    .AllowAnyHeader()
                    .AllowAnyMethod();
            });
        });
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
    {
        app.UseCors("default");

        app.UseAuthentication();

        app.UseMvc();
    }
}
```

}

**Api (Identity Controller)**

```
[Route("[controller]")]
[Authorize]
public class IdentityController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult Get()
    {
        return new JsonResult(from c in User.Claims select new { c.Type, c.Value });
    }
}
```

**QuickstartIdentityServer (startup.cs)**

```
 public class Startup
{


    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddMvc();

        string connectionString = @"Data Source=DOTNET-Foo;Initial Catalog=IdentityServer4;Integrated Security=True";
        var migrationsAssembly = typeof(Startup).GetTypeInfo().Assembly.GetName().Name;

        // configure identity server with in-memory stores, keys, clients and scopes
        services.AddIdentityServer()
            .AddDeveloperSigningCredential()
            .AddTestUsers(Config.GetUsers())
            // this adds the config data from DB (clients, resources)
            .AddConfigurationStore(options =>
            {
                options.ConfigureDbContext = builder =>
                    builder.UseSqlServer(connectionString,
                        sql => sql.MigrationsAssembly(migrationsAssembly));
            });
            // this adds the operational data from DB (codes, tokens, consents)
            //.AddOperationalStore(options =>
            //{
            //    options.ConfigureDbContext = builder =>
            //        builder.UseSqlServer(connectionString,
            //            sql => sql.MigrationsAssembly(migrationsAssembly));

        //    // this enables automatic token cleanup. this is optional.
        //    options.EnableTokenCleanup = true;
        //    options.TokenCleanupInterval = 30;
        //});

        services.AddAuthentication()
            .AddGoogle("Google", options =>
            {
                options.SignInScheme = IdentityServerConstants.ExternalCookieAuthenticationScheme;

                options.ClientId = "434483408261-55tc8n0cs4ff1fe21ea8df2o443v2iuc.apps.googleusercontent.com";
                options.ClientSecret = "3gcoTrEDPPJ0ukn_aYYT6PWo";
            })
            .AddOpenIdConnect("oidc", "OpenID Connect", options =>
            {
                options.SignInScheme = IdentityServerConstants.ExternalCookieAuthenticationScheme;
                options.SignOutScheme = IdentityServerConstants.SignoutScheme;

                options.Authority = "https://demo.identityserver.io/";
                options.ClientId = "implicit";

                options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                {
                    NameClaimType = "name",
                    RoleClaimType = "role"
                };
            });

    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
           // IdentityServerDatabaseInitialization.InitializeDatabase(app);
        }
        app.UseIdentityServer();
        app.UseStaticFiles();
        app.UseMvcWithDefaultRoute();
    }
}
```

I'm not able to access **http://localhost:5000/.well-known/openid-configuration**

[image]

Comment: you're enabling cors, just don't :|

Comment: "just don't" is no good advice. CORS is required for a lot of architectures. "make sure you know what you're doing" is better.

Answer (score 0):

I think the sample doesn't work anymore when you run the projects from IIS because the addresses, or more precisely the ports, are not the same.

### Ports used when run in IIS Express

When you run the projects through Visual Studio or use `dotnet run`, the URL over which the project is hosted is driven by a file called `launchSettings.json` in the `Properties` folder of your project.

- `IdentityServer` is hosted over `http://localhost:5000` - [Link to `launchSettings.json`](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4.Samples/blob/30d10c75e8747deffab71e56b4e7f742b06ee6d2/Quickstarts/8_EntityFrameworkStorage/src/QuickstartIdentityServer/Properties/launchSettings.json#L6)
- `JavaScriptClient` is hosted over port `http://localhost:5003` - [Link to `launchSettings.json`](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4.Samples/blob/30d10c75e8747deffab71e56b4e7f742b06ee6d2/Quickstarts/8_EntityFrameworkStorage/src/JavaScriptClient/Properties/launchSettings.json#L6)
- `Api` is accessible at `http://localhost:5002` - [Link to `launchSettings.json`](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4.Samples/blob/30d10c75e8747deffab71e56b4e7f742b06ee6d2/Quickstarts/8_EntityFrameworkStorage/src/Api/Properties/launchSettings.json#L6)

### Associated configuration

Knowing this there's a few configuration settings that come into play; let's go together over them.

#### Client settings in IdentityServer

When you define a client (i.e. an application that will federate its authentication to IdentityServer), you get to specify a few things, like:

- to which URL(s) is IdentityServer allowed to redirect the user after logging in or logging out;
- if this is a JS client, from which URL(s) should the browser be allowed to initiate an authorisation request

This can be found in the `Config` class [over here](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4.Samples/blob/30d10c75e8747deffab71e56b4e7f742b06ee6d2/Quickstarts/8_EntityFrameworkStorage/src/QuickstartIdentityServer/Config.cs#L87-L104).

You'll notice that all the URLs specified in that config point to where the `JavaScriptClient` is hosted when using IIS Express; you'll need to update those to the URL of the JS client when deployed to IIS.

#### JS configuration

Since in this example, the JS client makes a request directly to IdentityServer, some settings are defined in the JS application itself; we can find them in the [`app.js`](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4.Samples/blob/30d10c75e8747deffab71e56b4e7f742b06ee6d2/Quickstarts/8_EntityFrameworkStorage/src/JavaScriptClient/wwwroot/app.js#L21-L28) file:

- `authority` is the IdentityServer URL - `localhost:5000` is correct when we use IIS Express
- `redirect_uri` and `post_logout_redirect_uri` use `localhost:5003` which is the JS client URL when we use IIS Express

Again, you'll need to update all those values to match the URLs where both the applications are hosted when you use IIS.

#### API configuration

This sample shows how the JS client can make a request to the API and have it send the token to IdentityServer to validate it.

There are a few settings involved here:

- The JS client needs to know the URL of the API - this is defined again in [`app.js`](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4.Samples/blob/30d10c75e8747deffab71e56b4e7f742b06ee6d2/Quickstarts/8_EntityFrameworkStorage/src/JavaScriptClient/wwwroot/app.js#L46) in the JS client
- The API needs to know how to reach IdentityServer - we'll find this in [`Startup.cs`](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4.Samples/blob/30d10c75e8747deffab71e56b4e7f742b06ee6d2/Quickstarts/8_EntityFrameworkStorage/src/Api/Startup.cs#L17-L24) of the API
- The API needs to allow, through a CORS policy, the browser to make an AJAX request to its endpoints, and that again is done in the [`Startup` class](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4.Samples/blob/30d10c75e8747deffab71e56b4e7f742b06ee6d2/Quickstarts/8_EntityFrameworkStorage/src/Api/Startup.cs#L26-L34) in the API project

Once more, you'll need to update all those URLs to match the ones used when you deploy your projects to IIS.

Hopefully I didn't miss anything ;-)

Comment: Thanks Mickael for this answer .. i went though the steps which you mentioned even though i am unable to get it , but if i  run "Identiserver" using visual studio and remaining Api in (iis - port 5001) and javascript in iis port 5003 it is working fine...

but only if i run identityserver in port iis 5000 javascript client throwing error (iis port 5003)

Comment: Ha, so you've been using the same ports in IIS Express and IIS? If this is the case, my answer is way off. Can you please check if you can access http://localhost:5000/.well-known/openid-configuration when IdentityServer runs on IIS?

Comment: Actually i 'm not able to access that url but i can able to access "localhost:5000" but not  **localhost:5000/.well-known/openid-configuration**

Comment: Alright. At this stage I would recommend to enable the developer exception page in all environments by removing the [`if` clause](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4.Samples/blob/30d10c75e8747deffab71e56b4e7f742b06ee6d2/Quickstarts/8_EntityFrameworkStorage/src/QuickstartIdentityServer/Startup.cs#L72-L75) in the IdSrv pipeline setup and see what it comes up with. To be clear, you need to keep the `app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();` bit, just take it out of the `if`.

Comment: I just tried to run the quickstart #8 myself and found I needed to run the project with a specific parameter for the DB to be created and the migrations applied. From a command prompt, go to the `src\QuickstartIdentityServer` directory and run `dotnet run /seed`.

Comment: Thank you very much mickael , i enabled developer exception and it is showing SqlException: Cannot open database "IdentityServer4" requested by the login. The login failed.
Login failed for user 'IIS APPPOOL\IdServer' 
**After giving the login permission it  worked....**

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to do anything special here, ISD4 handles CORS properly out of the box. You need to specify http://localhost:5003 in the CORS origins for your client config. IDS4 will pick this up and allow the request to the discovery endpoint.

Answer (score 0):

Finally i solved the problem by giving the sql login permission for Login failed for user 'IIS APPPOOL\IdServe

Answer (score 0):

I fixed problem by open IdentityServer port in firewall.

Struggling to much time for fixing this

Answer (score 0):

I was running into this issue also with an Angular 9 app and a .net core web api project deployed to Azure in separate app services/endpoints.  I am using Azure DevOps for CI/CD and ultimately what I realized is that in the deployed web.config for the API I had:

```
    <environmentVariable name="ASPNETCORE_HTTPS_PORT" value="44340"/>
    <environmentVariable name="ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT" value="Development"/>
```

This was causing an issue because the WebHostBuilder was then using my Development configuration to initialize the Configuration for the Startup class, and that is why localhost was being used at all, since that is what is specified in my appsettings.Development.json file (my understanding - if I have it wrong I'm sure somebody will chime in :)).

I added a web.Staging.config file to my project with

```
    <environmentVariable name="ASPNETCORE_HTTPS_PORT" value="443" xdt:Locator="Match(name)" xdt:Transform="Replace"/>
    <environmentVariable name="ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT" value="Staging" xdt:Locator="Match(name)" xdt:Transform="Replace"/>
```

and my CI build is now transforming the web.config and my deployed ecosystem is healthy.